# Gradle script to clone code down from GitLab

Tags: gradle, gitlab

Am very new to Gradle and I wanted to know if there is a way to clone code down from GitLab.

I've looked at the Gradle repository [documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N1060B) to no avail.

Am supposing it’s something along the lines of the below or am I way off?

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url = 'http://central.megacorp.com/main/repo'
    credentials {
      username 'repouser'
      password 'badly-protected-secret'
    }
  }
}
```

For clarity the URL am trying to pull from looks something like: https://mysite.com/my-group/my-project.git

Thanks all.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Clone or pull from a Git repo?

Comment: Am looking to Clone. I've updated the question.

Comment: `maven` is for Maven repositories (which host binaries, not source code). For cloning a Git repo, you'd have to check out one of the third-party Git plugins.